# Migrate SQL Server database from Azure to AWS

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, azure-sql-server

I need to migrate a SQL Server database from Azure to AWS. I've tried to create a backup on Azure but it seems that option is not available, not even through a script.

Comment: Googling "migrate SQL DB from Azure to AWS" led me to this: http://www.cloudten.com.au/migrating-sql-databases-from-azure-to-aws-walkthrough/

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if exists an option to backup in Azure, as you said. However, you can export your database to a .BACPAC file and import it in a local instance of SQL Server. Then you can create a .bak file from this database to export to the AWS.

To export your database to a bacpac file, you can follow this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-export

Comment: I'll try this, actually i've tried this yesterday but i got a couple erros, i will work on fix these errors. Thank you very much, Renato.

Comment: Thanks, I know this way and already successful,  but I'm trying to find another way to migrate directly from Azure to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You have at least a few options here:

1. You can indeed create a backup in Azure. The backup file will get stored in a Storage account you set up. You can then download this and transfer it to your AWS VM (or RDS services) and restore it. I believe the manual backup you create in Azure is in the form of a .BACPAC file, which is just a compressed backup file.
2. You can create an empty database in AWS, sync the two schemas using something like RedGate or SSDT (which is free) and then use SSIS to move the data over. Or you could use scripts if you wanted. This would be a better option if you wanted to move your data over piecemeal.
3. You can use features in SSMS to copy the database directly from Azure and directly to AWS. Personally though I've never had a great deal of luck moving databases like this.